# Nodejs Api parameter passing and console log the parameter

Tags: node.js, express

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.get('/products/productList/:id', (res, req) => {
   console.log("product Id - " + req.params.id);
});
```

What is wrong in this code ? What can i do to avoid the following error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
at app.get (E:\Projects\Craiglist\trial\app.js:46:46)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\Projects\Craiglist\trial\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (E:\Projects\Craiglist\trial\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (E:\Projects\Craiglist\trial\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\Projects\Craiglist\trial\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at E:\Projects\Craiglist\trial\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
at param (E:\Projects\Craiglist\trial\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:354:14)
at param (E:\Projects\Craiglist\trial\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:365:14)
at Function.process_params (E:\Projects\Craiglist\trial\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:410:3)
at next (E:\Projects\Craiglist\trial\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
```

Comment: flagging as of topic because typo

Answer (score 3):

```
(res, req)
```

You changed the order of function params :)

Request is the first parameter, response is second.

Try this:

```
app.get('/products/productList/:id', (req, res) => {
   console.log("product Id - " + req.params.id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've `required`  `body-parser`. And use `bodyParser.urlencoded`.

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

This should be before your `.get` route definition.

you must do `npm install body-parser` before

Comment: bodyParser isnt required to decode req.params. 
This not cause problem.